# c++ nested loop performance

Tags: c++, performance, loops

I have basically two vectors one for a large number of elements and a second for a small number of probes used to sample data of the elements. I stumbled upon the question in which order to implement the two loops. Naturally I thought having the outer loop over the larger vector would be beneficially

**Implementation 1:**

```
for(auto& elem: elements) {
    for(auto& probe: probes) {
        probe.insertParticleData(elem);
    }
}
```

However it seems that the second implementation takes only  half of the time

**Implementation 2:**

```
for(auto& probe: probes) {
    for(auto& elem: elements) {
        probe.insertParticleData(elem);
    }
}
```

What could be the reason for that?

**Edit:**

Timings were generated by the following code

```
clock_t t_begin_ps = std::clock();
... // timed code
clock_t t_end_ps = std::clock();
double elapsed_secs_ps = double(t_end_ps - t_begin_ps) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

and on inserting the elements data I do basically two things, testing if the distance to the probe is below a limit and the computing an average

```
probe::insertParticleData (const elem& pP) {
   if (!isInside(pP.position())) {return false;}
   ... // compute alpha and beta
   avg_vel = alpha*avg_vel + beta*pP.getVel();
   return true;
}
```

To get an idea of the memory usage I have approx. 10k elements which are objects with 30 double data members. For the test I used 10 probes containing 15 doubles.

Comment: First of all, how did you measure the timings?

Comment: That may also depend of what `probe.insertParticleData(elem);` does.

Comment: It really depends on the number and sizes of the elements, and the memory access pattern. Could you add some more detail ?

Comment: @Jarod42 added implementation of insertParticleData

Comment: @Bathsheba, I included the code for the timings

Comment: Presumably you have two versions of the program, exactly equivalent aside from the loop. Then run them a few times and compute the mean and standard error of the sample. Not perfect but a little more scientific. Also, remove `insertParticleData` or set it to be a `no-op` to isolate the difference to the loop. If `insertParticleData` modifies the containers then it's a rather boring explanation.

Comment: Yes I compiled two different versions of the code and run them several times, having always approx. a factor of two between them.

Comment: @PaulR I updated the question with some numbers and sizes

Answer (score 5):

Todays CPUs are heavily optimized for linear access to memory. Therefore a few long loops will beat many short loops. You want the inner loop to iterate over the long vector.

Comment: What does linear access mean exactly?

Comment: Linear in this context generally means contiguous - loading whole cache lines and using only part of each cache line is inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

My guess:
if insertParticleData is virtual, the compiler will treat the function's address as a constant within the inner loop and move the vtable fetch outside the inner loop.
I.e. effectively generate code which looks like:

```
   for (auto& probe: probes) {
      funcPtr p = probe.insertParticleData;
      for (auto& elem: elements) {
        (*p)(elem);
      }
   }
```

whereas in the first version, p would be computed for every inner iteration.

Comment: No it is not a virtual function